# Adding a WHERE clause to a Group Join

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am working in VB.NET.  I have two datatables (table & table2), which are identical.  The two columns in question are:

id  | voided_id 
1   | null 
2   | null 
3   | 2

table1 is the list of items, and table2 is the list of voided items.  so, if an item has voided an earlier item, I want to exclude the voided item.  In this example id 2 would be excluded because it was voided by id 3.

Here is what I have so far:

```
                Dim compareResults = From table In resultOds
                                     Group Join table2 In voidOds
                                         On table.Field(Of Int64)("id") Equals table2.Field(Of Int64?)("voided_loan_id")
                                         Into tablesJoin = Group From tableJoin In tablesJoin.Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Int64?)("voided_loan_id") Is Nothing).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     Select table
```

right now, I get everything.  The WHERE clause inside the group join isn't working.  Any suggestions?

Many articles I found said .DefaultIfEmpty() should provide the functionality of the WHERE but this returns everything as well:

```
                Dim compareResults2 = From table In resultOds
                                      Group Join table2 In voidOds
                                         On table.Field(Of Int64)("id") Equals table2.Field(Of Int64?)("voided_loan_id") Into tablesJoin = Group
                                      From table2 In tablesJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      Select table
```

based on some off-line input I got, I rewrote this as a subquery.  Still returns everything.

```
Dim compareResults2 = From r In resultOds
                                      Where Not (From v In voidOds Where v.Field(Of Int64?)("voided_loan_id") IsNot Nothing Select v.Field(Of Int64?)("voided_loan_id")).Contains(r.Field(Of Int64?)("id"))
                                      Select r
```

Comment: I'm not finding it very clear that you have two identical tables but they have separate contents, or do they? The example table isn't really making sense with the description either. Can you re-explain what your tables look like and what you're expecting as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

C#

```
var s =ItemTable.Where(i=>!VoidedItem.Any(v=>v.id==i.id))?.ToList();
```

VB

```
Dim s = ItemTable.Where(Function(i) Not VoidedItem.Any(Function(v) v.id = i.id))?.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it working so I defaulted to executing a SQL string. thanks for the feedback.